# Folding or concatMap-ing an Aeson Array via lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

I've been starting at https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-aeson-1.0.2/Data-Aeson-Lens.html and https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-4.16.1/Control-Lens-Fold.html trying to figure out how to write an expression that allows me to construct something of the following type:

```
import Data.Aeson as A

functionIWant 
  :: (Vector A.Value)
  -> (A.Value -> [a])
  -> [a]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two lens functions that are used to "lift" regular `Foldable`-related functions to the lensy world:

- [`folded`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:folded) that folds over all the elements of a `Foldable` container, in this case it would be the `Vector`.
- [`folding`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:folding) that lifts a function that returns a `Foldable` result.

You can compose them into a new `Fold` and then use [`toListOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:toListOf) to obtain the final list.

There is also an analogue of `folded` for `Traversable`, called [`traversed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:traversed).

Comment: Also, here's a Git repo with some lens-aeson examples: https://github.com/danidiaz/lens-aeson-examples