# Unable to collect values from a nested JSON using lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

### Edit

I have managed to get my answer after trying several random permutation. But I still don't understand why the former works, but the latter doesn't:

```
x ^.. (key "conversations") . values . (key "id") . _String

-- vs

x ^@.. (key "conversations") . values . (imap (\ _ v -> v ^? key "id"))
```

### Original Question

I have a JSON with the following shape:

```
{
  "conversations":[
    {"id":"abc", ...}, 
    {"id":"abc", ...}, 
    {"id":"abc", ...}, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to get `conversations.*.id` using the following expression...

```
x ^@.. (key "conversations") . values . (imap (\ _ v -> v ^? key "id"))
```

...which results in the following compiler error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe’
                     with ‘Const
                             (base-4.13.0.0:Data.Semigroup.Internal.Endo [(Int, Value)])’
      Expected type: IndexedGetting
                       Int
                       (base-4.13.0.0:Data.Semigroup.Internal.Endo [(Int, Value)])
                       BSL.ByteString
                       Value
        Actual type: Indexed
                       Int
                       Value
                       (Const
                          (base-4.13.0.0:Data.Semigroup.Internal.Endo [(Int, Value)]) Value)
                     -> BSL.ByteString -> Maybe BSL.ByteString
```

[values](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.0/lens-aeson-1.0.1/Data-Aeson-Lens.html#v:values) seems to be an "An *indexed* Traversal into Array elements" and `imap` seems to be a `FunctorWithIndex`, so why won't this compose as expected? What am I missing?

PS: I noticed that I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906616/folding-or-concatmap-ing-an-aeson-array-via-lenses) about 2 years ago. Is this question conceptually the same? Am I missing some basic understanding of lenses?

Answer (score 0):

> I have managed to get my answer after trying several random
>   permutation. But I still don't understand why the former works, but
>   the latter doesn't:
>
> ```
> x ^.. (key "conversations") . values . (key "id") . _String
>
> -- vs
>
> x ^@.. (key "conversations") . values . (imap (\ _ v -> v ^? key "id"))
> ```

[`imap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.1/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:imap) is a mapping function, a variation of `fmap` that gives access to an index. It is not an optic, and so you can't compose it with other optics in that way. While there is an indexed setter version of `imap`, [`imapped`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.1/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:imapped), it still wouldn't help, because `(^..)` requires a fold, and `(^@..)`, an indexed fold. [`key`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html#v:key), on the other hand, sets up a traversal that can be used to retrieve specific properties in the way you intended, because all traversals are folds.

Comment: Would you be able to explain WHY `imap` cannot be composed the way I was expected to compose it? Is it a "regular" function, i.e. nothing to do with lenses?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda Yes, part of the issue is that `imap` doesn't have the right type. There is an indexed setter version of `imap`, `imapped` (which is to `imap` what `mapped` is to plain `fmap`), but it still wouldn't do what you want. A setter can only modify targets, and not retrieve them. Since you are trying to retrieve elements with `(^..)`, a setter won't help: you need a fold. `key "id"` is a traversal, and every traversal is a fold, so it works properly.